# Small table and small figure next to each other

Tags: tables, floats, layout

Any tips on how to put these two together (see image upload). Current code:

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,english, onehalfspacing, nolistspacing, liststotoc, headsepline, oneside, chapterinoneline, reqno, a4paper, toctotoc]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

  \begin{table}[!htb] \centering
        \small \caption{}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
        \toprule\toprule
        & Individual variance\\ \midrule
        AAPL & 0.76 \\
        BA & 0.55 \\
        CBRE & 0.60 \\
        CMG & 0.91 \\
        DIS & 0.58 \\
        GOLD & \cellcolor{red!25}1.00 \\
        IBM & 0.64 \\
        KO & 0.69 \\
        MD & \cellcolor{green!25}0.0050 \\
        MMM & 0.43 \\
        NKE & 0.72 \\ \midrule \midrule
        \end{tabular}
        \end{table} \label{tab 1.5}
        %
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{Figures/biplot_factoran.eps}
            \caption{Biplot where $\mbox{FA}_1$ is on the $x$-axis and $\mbox{FA}_2$ is on the $y$-axis}
        \end{figure}
        %
```

[image: file]

Comment: [Table and figure side-by-side with independent captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6850/134144) might be helpful. Apart from that, please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages.

Comment: Was not able to implement the advice given in that post.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{cp{1cm}c}
\adjustbox{valign=m,addcode={% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/227051/121799
\begin{minipage}{\width}\captionof{table}{\label{tab 1.5}}}{\end{minipage}}}{
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\toprule\toprule
& Individual variance\\ \midrule
AAPL & 0.76 \\
BA & 0.55 \\
CBRE & 0.60 \\
CMG & 0.91 \\
DIS & 0.58 \\
GOLD & \cellcolor{red!25}1.00 \\
IBM & 0.64 \\
KO & 0.69 \\
MD & \cellcolor{green!25}0.0050 \\
MMM & 0.43 \\
NKE & 0.72 \\ \midrule \midrule
\end{tabular}} & &
\adjustbox{valign=m,addcode={%
\begin{minipage}{\width}}{\captionof{figure}{Biplot where $\text{FA}_1$ is on the $x$-axis and $\text{FA}_2$ is on the $y$-axis}\end{minipage}}}{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-duck}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution using the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \CenterFloatBoxes
  \begin{floatrow}[2]
    \ttabbox[\FBwidth]{%
      \small 
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
        \toprule\toprule
        & Individual variance\\ \midrule
        AAPL & 0.76 \\
        BA & 0.55 \\
        CBRE & 0.60 \\
        CMG & 0.91 \\
        DIS & 0.58 \\
        GOLD & \cellcolor{red!25}1.00 \\
        IBM & 0.64 \\
        KO & 0.69 \\
        MD & \cellcolor{green!25}0.0050 \\
        MMM & 0.43 \\
        NKE & 0.72 \\ \midrule \midrule
        \end{tabular}}{%
      \caption{}}
  \killfloatstyle
    \ffigbox[0.5\textwidth]{%
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/biplot_factoran.eps}}{%
        \caption{Biplot where $\mbox{FA}_1$ is on the $x$-axis and $\mbox{FA}_2$ is on the $y$-axis}}
  \end{floatrow}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to switch to the excellent [KOMA-Script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle and use the report class `scrreprt`. It has all the necessary options built in. On page 133 in the manual, it islisted code that does exactly what you are asking for. Here is the code adapted to your MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{biplot_factoran}
\caption{Biplot where $\mbox{FA}_1$ is on the $x$-axis and $\mbox{FA}_2$ is on the $y$-axis}\label{fig:rechteck}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering\small
\captionaboveof{table}{}
\label{tab:rechteck}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
        \toprule
        & Individual variance\\ \midrule
        AAPL & 0.76 \\
        BA & 0.55 \\
        CBRE & 0.60 \\
        CMG & 0.91 \\
        DIS & 0.58 \\
        GOLD & \cellcolor{red!25}1.00 \\
        IBM & 0.64 \\
        KO & 0.69 \\
        MD & \cellcolor{green!25}0.0050 \\
        MMM & 0.43 \\
        NKE & 0.72 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Giving the output:

[image: Figure&Table]